# 2 Oracle SQL queries return different number of rows when number should be the same. Clause `IN`

Tags: oracle

2 Oracle SQL queries return different number of rows when number should be the same. At least I believe the number of rows should be the same.

Please see SQL query #1:

```
select count(*) from temp_dormer_mro
where catalog_number in (select catalog_number from temp_dormer_data);
```

It returns 961 rows.

Please see SQL query #2:

```
select count(*) from temp_dormer_data
where catalog_number in (select catalog_number from temp_dormer_mro);
```

It returns 1278 rows.

Please help me to understand why I got different number of rows for these 2 queries.

---------- Update #1 ------------

Data in tables looks like this:
[image: Data in tables]

There is no `NULL` values in any row.

Table **temp_dormer_data** has 1,278 records. So basically second SQL query just select all rows in that table.

---------- Update #2 ------------

```
select count(*) from temp_dormer_mro
join temp_dormer_data
    on temp_dormer_data.catalog_number = temp_dormer_mro.catalog_number
;

select count(*) from temp_dormer_data
join temp_dormer_mro
    on temp_dormer_mro.catalog_number = temp_dormer_data.catalog_number
;
```

Both above SQL queries return 1,278 rows. And that number seems to be correct. But why the first SQL query returns incorrect number?

Comment: *Table temp_dormer_data has 1,278 records.* ... and the table temp_dormer_mro contains ___ records? *why I got different number of rows for these 2 queries* Because they realizes different logic.

Comment: prediction: `temp_dormer_data` contains duplicates by `catalog_number`

Comment: @Akina you are right, there are duplicates.

Comment: If so then I don't understand why you're surprized. `WHERE 1 IN (1, 1, 1)` produces one "true", not three.